# Background Image need to give innner div space

Tags: html, css

I would like to give a space of repeating background.

Tried Code :

```css
#bg_img {
  background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/diagonal-lines-vector-background-design_1017-12303.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg_img">
  <div id="tbles">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="4%" align="center"><strong>No</strong></td>
          <td style="min-width:25%" align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
          <td style="min-width:11%" align="center"><strong>Unit</strong></td>
          <td style="width:11%" align="center"><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">1.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 1</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">FIRE BARRIER CAULK</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">780.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">2.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 2</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">INTUMESCENT STRIP</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">73,600.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">3.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 3</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">STAINLESS STEEL HOOP</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">25.00</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">4.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 4</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">COATED FIRESTOP BOARD</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">125.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">5.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 5</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">MORTAR</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">185.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to display Background Images on specific Area only with using backgroud space, margin or padding?

Actual Result :

[image]

Expected Result :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add extra empty element, you can consider multiple background where you can add white layers above the background to control the space. Simply adjust the background-size of each layer to reduce/increase the space:

```css
#bg_img {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left  /2% 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right /2% 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top   /100% 25px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom/100% 10px no-repeat,
    url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/diagonal-lines-vector-background-design_1017-12303.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div id="bg_img">
  <div id="tbles">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="4%" align="center"><strong>No</strong></td>
          <td style="min-width:25%" align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
          <td style="min-width:11%" align="center"><strong>Unit</strong></td>
          <td style="width:11%" align="center"><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">1.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 1</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">FIRE BARRIER CAULK</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">780.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">2.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 2</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">INTUMESCENT STRIP</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">73,600.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">3.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 3</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">STAINLESS STEEL HOOP</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">25.00</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">4.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 4</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">COATED FIRESTOP BOARD</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">125.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">5.</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 5</strong><br>
            <font style="font-size:11px;">MORTAR</font>
          </td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
          <td class="materialRow" align="center">185.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your `table` structure with `thead` and apply `background-image` to `tbody`. You also have blank column to achieve the requirement. Mentioned changes done in the below code snippet. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
#bg_img tbody {
    background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/diagonal-lines-vector-background-design_1017-12303.jpg");
            background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    }
    
.blank-row {
  padding: 1%;
}

tbody tr td:first-child,
tbody tr td:last-child{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg_img">
  <div id="tbles">
       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="2%"></th>
              <th width="4%" align="center"><strong>No</strong></th>
              <th style="min-width:25%" align="center"><strong>Name</strong></th>
              <th style="min-width:11%" align="center"><strong>Unit</strong></th>
              <th style="width:11%" align="center"><strong>Unit Price</strong></th>
              <th width="2%"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="blank-row" colspan="6"></td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">1.</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 1</strong><br><font style="font-size:11px;">FIRE BARRIER CAULK</font></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">780.00</td>
              <td></td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">2.</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 2</strong><br><font style="font-size:11px;">INTUMESCENT STRIP</font></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">73,600.00</td>
              <td></td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">3.</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 3</strong><br><font style="font-size:11px;">STAINLESS STEEL HOOP</font></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">25.00</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
              <td></td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">4.</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 4</strong><br><font style="font-size:11px;">COATED FIRESTOP BOARD</font></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">125.00</td>
              <td></td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">5.</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="left"><strong>Banana 5</strong><br><font style="font-size:11px;">MORTAR</font></td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">Test</td>
              <td class="materialRow" align="center">185.00</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="blank-row" colspan="6"></td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, little more if possible need space in tbody -> top, bottom, right also, shown in the screenshot.(showing space TD also)

Comment: @GhanshyamNakiya please review the above code snippet. Thanks